# Isomorphisms in a Category

Tags: category-theory

Let $a,b,c$ be morphisms. Prove that if $ba$ and $cb$ are isomorphisms, then $a,b,c$ are isomorphisms. How do I show this?

Does it follow from the commutativity of the diagrams since $b(ba)^{-1}a = 1$ and $ab(ba)^{-1} = 1$?

Comment: How do you get $b(ba)^{-1}a=1$ and $ab(ba)^{-1}=1$?

Comment: Through the commutative diagram with arrows $a,b,ba$. To go from the domain of $a$ and back, you go $a$, $b$, $(ba)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

Since $ba$ and $cb$ are isomorphisms, we have
$$
ba(ba)^{-1}=1 \quad\text{and}\quad (cb)^{-1}cb=1.
$$
Thus
$$
a(ba)^{-1}=(1)a(ba)^{-1}=((cb)^{-1}cb)a(ba)^{-1}
=(cb)^{-1}c(ba(ba)^{-1})
=(cb)^{-1}c.
$$
Hence $x:=a(ba)^{-1}=(cb)^{-1}c$ satisfies $bx=xb=1$. Therefore $b$ is isomorphism.
Then $a=b^{-1}(ba)$ is a composition of isomorphisms, and similarly for $c$.